# WAF Policy attachment to Application Gateway, and REST API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-application-gateway

Is there not a way to create an application gateway with waf_v2 sku and have a WAF policy attached using the rest api?

With this code i can deploy the application gateway

```
    "webApplicationFirewallConfiguration" = @{
        "disabledRuleGroups" = @()
        "enabled" = $true
        "exclusions" = @()
        "fileUploadLimitInMb" = 100
        "firewallMode" = "Detection"
        "maxRequestBodySizeinKb" = 128
        "requestBodyCheck"       = $true
        "ruleSetType"        = "OWASP"
        "ruleSetVersion"     = "3.1"
    }
```

But if i removed that and put instead

```
    "firewallPolicy"      = @{
        "id" = "path to WAF Policy"
    }
```

I am getting the following return:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ApplicationGatewayFirewallNotConfiguredForSelectedSku",
    "message": "Application Gateway (Path to gateway) with the selected SKU tier WAF_v2 must have a valid WAF policy or configuration",
    "details": []
  }
}
```

I have added "forceFirewallPolicyAssociation" = $true but that hasnt seemed to help. Has anyone worked with the REST API and the application gateways? I have been at this for about 16 hours and am at my wits end. AKS wasn't this hard to deploy via rest api... Any help is appreciated

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-gateway/application-gateways/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting all 3 items together. It then deployed with the external policy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue in the `2022-01-01` version. At least i get the same error in Bicep. Rolling back to `2021-08-01` works.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know im not crazy.